# Laravel: Cannot use helper inside php shorthand array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

PHP version 5.6. Code:

```
protected $siteServices = [
        1 => [
            'title' =>  'Consulting',
            'key'       =>  'service',
            'description'   =>  '',
            'file'  =>  asset('assets/img/sample/image1.jpg'), // throws error on this line
        ],
];
```

Error: **`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ']'`**

What would be a possible fix for this?

**Edit**
Solved by moving the variable in the running function instead of making it `protected`. Also can be solved by declaring the empty variable first then set the values in `__constructor()`

Comment: I believe this is not a duplicate.

Comment: The other question involves passing data to an object while the OP of this question is trying to invoke a function inside an array in an object oriented context.

Comment: Well it's all the same. If one needs to initialize this array, can do it in the constructor.

Comment: But thats ugly @RoyalBg

Comment: @HassanAlthaf why ugly? It's just the consturctor calling the `setSiteService` method you have suggested

Comment: @RoyalBg Thats like, ew....

Comment: @HassanAlthaf why so? That's what constructor is. For initializing class member, isn't it? What is your point to not do it? Does the person instantiating the class needs to be aware that he lately needs to call `setSiteService` method? It should be encapsulated internal logical.

Comment: @RoyalBg In my opinion, I prefer using the constructor only to pass dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done but it in a different way. I have listed two different methods.

**First method**

```
protected $siteServices = [
    1 => [
        'title' =>  'Consulting',
        'key'       =>  'service',
        'description'   =>  '',
        'file'  =>  ['asset', 'assets/img/sample/image1.jpg'] // throws error on this line
    ]
];
```

I replaced the function call with an array assigned to the file key in this array. So, now, you'd be wondering how you could call the asset function, yeah? It is pretty simple.

While you are looping through that array, you can do this:

`call_user_func($siteServices[1]['file'][0], $siteServices[1]['file'][1]);`

So, what are we doing here?

Firstly, we set an array to the file key where the first element of the array is the name of the function, while the other element is the value for the parameter that needs to be passed to the function defined previously.

So, using the PHP's [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) function, you can call functions giving their name and the parameters. I hope this helps you out.

---

**Second method**

I am pretty sure you will have a setter function for this property. Therefore, you could do something like this:

```
public function setSiteService($title, $key, $description, $file)
{
    $file = asset($file);

    $service = [
        'title' => $title,
        'key' => $key,
        'description' => $description,
        'file' => $file
    ];

    $this->siteServices[] = $service;
}
```

So, the setter does the processing part for you. Hardcoding arrays is not at all a good idea, you should definitely populate through some mechanism.

Comment: This only works if he manually handles the array later and not if it's part from a framework which handles it by some convention

Comment: Well, that is the best thing. Otherwise, I have another way.

Comment: but the problem does not make sense, you can call a function as a value and its result will be the value

Comment: @RoyalBg Well, it is PHP. You can't expect everything in it to work. I tried different mockup functions for him, and I failed. I think the call_user_func is a great alternative, or the one I just put. Check the second method.

Comment: You should expect it to work, well, people rely on PHP for real projects. Yes, the second way is better. Yet we need to find where the problem comes from, it's certainly not from that function call.

Comment: Oh, I see, it's a class member, it needs it to be initialized at compile time.

Comment: I experimented, and tried out stuff..... It doesn't work mate.

Comment: It does work for normal arrays. And does not work for values of object members. The best one can achieve is to assign the result manually after the object creation as in your second way.

Comment: Yes. I hope the OP likes this..